# Why the error occured when i tried to send a POST request with QWebEngineHttpRequest (PyQt5)?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qt5

I try to get JSON Object from source, but getting only errors.
Now I'm trying to understand what I'm doing wrong.
This code works well with other resources.
Maybe It`s not problem with code, but with web-source.

```
import sys
import json
from PyQt5.QtCore import QByteArray, QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineCore import QWebEngineHttpRequest
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEnginePage, QWebEngineSettings
from pprint import pprint


def on_load_finished():
    """Handle response"""
    engine.toPlainText(handle_to_html)  # get json


def handle_to_html(html):
    """Handle html"""
    print(html)
    QApplication.quit()


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    engine = QWebEnginePage()
    url = "https://sportsapi.betway.com/api/Events/V2/GetEvents"
    request = QWebEngineHttpRequest(url=QUrl(url), method=QWebEngineHttpRequest.Post)
    request.setHeader(QByteArray(b"Content-Type"), QByteArray(b"application/json"))

    payload = {
        "LanguageId": 1,
        "ClientTypeId": 2,
        "BrandId": 3,
        "JurisdictionId": 1,
        "ClientIntegratorId": 1,
        "ExternalIds": [9032262, 9038528, 9037778],
        "MarketCName": "win-draw-win",
        "ScoreboardRequest": {"ScoreboardType": 3, "IncidentRequest": {}},
        "BrowserId": 3,
        "OsId": 3,
        "ApplicationVersion": "",
        "BrowserVersion": "97.0.4692.99",
        "OsVersion": "NT 10.0",
        "SessionId": "null",
        "TerritoryId": 227,
        "CorrelationId": "06779075-21e2-4ba8-8e91-d71a981621fe",
        "VisitId": "d1088cdf-13a8-42d0-be90-b34fd1332c36",
        "ViewName": "sports",
        "JourneyId": "833a4c0c-3354-499f-9d52-949df6d159f9",
    }
    request.setPostData(bytes(json.dumps(payload), "utf-8"))
    engine.load(request)
    engine.loadFinished.connect(on_load_finished)
    app.exec_()
```

Errors are looks like

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

<Error>
<Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
</Error>
```

Maybe It`s not problem with code, but with web-source.

Comment: That error comes from?

Comment: M..when I make POST request, frome source

Comment: You need to be more clear. What do you mean by "source"?

Comment: @musicamante friend, i think u know how Get and Post are working, when I send Get method I`m w8 4 results, it can be JSON or html code, with POST method the same, I send POST request to API(https://sportsapi.betway.com/api/Events/V2/GetEvents) and getting error instead of JSON. Did u see my code? i don't understand your question

Comment: So, that "error" is what you print in `on_load_finished`? That was ***not*** clear from your question nor your comment: "from source" can mean a lot of things (your source code? the page source? the source of the request?), you must try to be more clear. That said: 1. `toPlainText` *tries* to convert the **rendered** [x]html, which in the case of an xml response of a web API might result in an unformattable text; 2. even considering that, the *actual* error is in the response, and it's probably due to a malformed request (you mistyped some keywords, or some data is invalid/not accepted).

Comment: @musicamante, yes, u are right! its what I print in on_load_finished. 
Ok, unterstand, sry for misunderstanding. 
So, maybe you know, how can I get JSON with POST request, is it possibel to make with QWebEngineHttpRequest? I can use requests librarry, but it wont work, cause Cloudflare

Comment: The problem is not in using QWebEngineHttpRequest, but the fact that the request was not accepted for some reason. In any case, to interact with a web API you don't need the QtWebEngine framework, as QNetworkAccessManager with QNetworkRequest sent with `POST` will suffice.

Comment: @musicamante, friend, also I found another results, when I`m send another format of msg, payload = [ { info} ], then I`m getting: 
"MethodResult":"ERROR","Errors":"Message":"Invalid request object for: GetEventsResultV2","ErrorType":0,"Type":"Fieldset","IsCritical":true}]}

Comment: @musicamante Thank u for help friend!!!